# Regex To Match whole text anywhere in String & Return Line Value

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy, regex-group

I have a string of text example:

- Today is hot.
- Weather Is 18.
- Last Week Was 20.
- Yesterday Was Cold

I want to look for the key word say "Week" using regex match and it returns me the whole line "Last Week Was 20"

I have used .*Week. * which works but it matches individual letters as well so if I was to change to just W will still match when I want it to find a match on the whole phrase.

Also \bWeek\b will return just the work Week and not the Line.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want `.*\bWeek\b.*`

Comment: Does it work???

Answer (score 0):

I would use this

> .+Week.+

Given the data of

> Today is hot.
>
> Weather Is 18.
>
> Last Week Was 20.
>
> Yesterday Was Cold

The result is:

> Last Week Was 20.